# I am in progress of something, it's that right?

Tags: tense, phrase-request

What should I say when I am in progress of what I am doing? Is this right?

> I am in progress of became a teacher.

Comment: Another way to phrase it, *I'm a teacher in progress*.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to say this would be:

> I am *making* progress (in order) to become a teacher.

If you check examples using *progress* you will find this form - [***progress***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/progress):

> 2. satisfactory development, growth, or advance: *she is **making progress** in maths*.

BTW, you cannot use *became* because your statement is not in the past.

Answer (score 1):

progress can be a noun a verb or an adjective.

I am making progress, learning to be a teacher.
or
I am in the progress of becoming a teacher.
or
I am progressing as a teacher.

Cite: Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary © 2006-2013 K Dictionaries Ltd.